# Live loading a React App in a specific URL

Tags: spring, reactjs, tomcat

I have an application which uses React as front-end and Spring as back-end, running on Tomcat.

When I deploy the application to my development server it runs on port 8443 successfully, but I have always to build my entire project and copy the generated .war file to webapps directory.

When I update only the front-end I need to redeploy my entire project and it really sucks.

I know that react has the `react-script start`, but it runs on port 3000 and I can't consume my back-end (cross origin problems).

Is there some solution to improve my productivity? Maybe something that reloads my files directly on server or a solution to consume my back-end from another port?

Comment: hope [this doc](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#integrating-with-an-api-backend) may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my `package.json` with

```
{
  /* ... */

  "proxy": "https://localhost:8443",

  /* ... */
}
```